# Cast "null" as null in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, sessionstorage

I use the session storage to set a key that can take numeric values or `null`. I noticed that the field is stored as a string no matter what I put in. Is there a nice way to convert back my stored value to `null` ?

For instance, I want to do a check in my code as such:

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('key')) {
   // do something
}
```

Whats the best way to make that check?
The obvious way would be

```
 if (!sessionStorage.getItem('key') !== "null") {
       // do something
 }
```

I am wondering if there's an alternative.

Comment: Why don't you just use `sessionStorage.removeItem('key')` instead of `sessionStorage.setItem('key','null')`?

Comment: For my use case, it's easier to manage. I have a dropdown menu to change set the value for `key`. it's binded to an event listerner, so it would be odd in one case to do a delete and in all other case to set the value no?

Comment: localStorage only stores strings, it has no concept of JavaScript types, so you should actually be checking for a specific string, be it `null`, `not set`, `0` or whatever you choose, or just remove the item and check that it's not set.

Comment: I actually think checking to see if it is a null string is the best way. Unless you wrap it in try ... catch, parsing would throw an error if you try to JSON.parse().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want something that would evaluate to false

You could use an empty string instead to mark the unset value:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key','');
```

This way you can re-use your current check:

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('key')) {
   // do something
}
```

---

That said, you mentioned you had a drop down to select values, and that's why you need such a value, but I think a solution involving deleting the item on the null value would be better. [Here's a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SeinopSys/ffebad9q/), and the code used to make it:

```js
var dd = document.getElementById('dropdown');

dd.addEventListener('change', function(){
  var value = this.value;
  if (value === 'null')
    sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
  else sessionStorage.setItem('key', value);
});

var check = document.getElementById('check');
check.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.innerHTML = 'Value: '+sessionStorage.getItem('key')+
                     ', check: '+(!sessionStorage.getItem('key'));
});
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="null">none</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<button id="check">Check value</button>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can parse it

```
JSON.parse('null') // null
JSON.parse('1')   //  1
```

so

```
var val = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
val = JSON.parse(val);
```

Close to cast

Alternative would be:

```
var val = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
val = val*1 || null;
```

Comment: Would work in those two cases, but what if the value is a String? `JSON.parse("Hello");` does not work.

Comment: @OptimusCrime he stores `numbers` or `null` that's what was described

Comment: Gotcha. I missed that part. Guess this is a nice, working, hack then.

Comment: JSON parsing is an overkill for this.

Answer (score 2):

Serialize your value as JSON before writing it to storage.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(val);
```

Then parse it when you read it out again.

```
try {
  var val = JSON.parse(storage.item);
} catch(ex) {
  // handle errors
}
```

It's important to wrap the parser in a try block. If the user or the browser clears the session storage, then you'd be trying to `JSON.parse('undefined')` which will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The sessionStorage is a key-value database where both are store as strings. You can see the documentation stating `DOMString` for both [Storage.setItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

The nature of this is then that the objects you retrieve will always be strings. You will have to cast them manually, either by applying `JSON.parse()` or a completely manual approach. There is no way to get back the `null` without any operations.

Another approach that has been mentioned is simply to avoid storing `null` values in the sessionStorage. It is easier to check if a key exists than to cast it correctly afterwards.

Comment: Ok obviously I am expecting to do an operation. It seems JSON.parse is the   way to go. Actually in my case, I just want something that would evaluate to false.

Comment: Technically, you could also `eval` it.

Answer (score -1):

Since the returned statements are in strings you can say `if(!sessionStorage.setItem('key','')) {}`